# Expand uitableview cell height while typing and avoid keyboard

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a tableview with textview. I want to set tableviewcell height according to the content of uitextview while typing and also if keyboard hides uitexview scroll table.

Below is the code for expanding cell height according to the content

```
func updateCellHeight(indexPath: NSIndexPath, comment: String,textview: UITextView) {

    let tempDict = arrayTexts[indexPath.row] as! NSMutableDictionary
    tempDict.setValue(comment, forKey: "content")
    arrayTexts[indexPath.row] = tempDict
    self.tblFields.beginUpdates()
    self.tblFields.endUpdates()


}
```

The above code is working but its not avoiding keyboard

Below code is for avoiding keyboard

```
func textviewBeginEditing(textview: UITextView) {
    let contentInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: keyboardHeight, right: 0)

    self.tblFields.contentInset = contentInsets
    self.tblFields.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets

    // If active text field is hidden by keyboard, scroll it so it's visible
    // Your app might not need or want this behavior.
    var aRect = self.view.frame
    aRect.size.height -= keyboardHeight

    if !aRect.contains(textview.frame.origin) {
        self.tblFields.scrollRectToVisible(textview.frame, animated: false)
    }

}
```

The above code sometimes avoids keyboard and sometimes not but the tableview continuously scrolls up on typing and is not working properly. Whats my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the code from textviewBeginEditing function and add following code

```
func updateCellHeight(indexPath: NSIndexPath, comment: String, textview: UITextView) {

    let tempDict = arrayTexts[indexPath.row] as! NSMutableDictionary
    tempDict.setValue(comment, forKey: "value")
    arrayTexts[indexPath.row] = tempDict

    if textview.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UIView.layoutFittingCompressedSize).height != textview.frame.size.height {

        UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
        self.tblFields.beginUpdates()
        self.tblFields.endUpdates()
        UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)

    }

}
```